# Observe a property change in the array object using Combine

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I am working on a solution to listen to the changes in the object. The code snippet below is the solution I am proceeding with.

Here I have to update the UI Whenever the isSelected bool changes.

```
class OfferDetail: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items: [OfferItem]
    private var anyCancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    init(deliveryAddress: String, deliveryDate: String, offerItems: [OfferItem]) {
        self.items = offerItems
        for item in items {
            item.$isSelected
            .sink(receiveValue: { _ in
                print("OfferDetail Update 1")
                self.objectWillChange.send()
            })
            .store(in: &anyCancellables)
        }
    }
}

class OfferItem: Identifiable, ObservableObject {
    @Published var isSelected: Bool = false
    let uuid = UUID()
    
    init() {
        print(uuid)
    }
    
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var offer: OfferDetail?
    private var anyCancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    init() {
        offer = OfferDetail(deliveryAddress: "", deliveryDate: "", offerItems: [OfferItem(), OfferItem()])
        offer?.$items.sink { items in
            print("ViewModel Update 2")
            
            for item in items {
                print(item.uuid, item.isSelected)
            }

        }.store(in: &anyCancellables)
    }
    
}

let viewModel = ViewModel()
viewModel.offer?.items.first?.isSelected = true
```

Is this the correct way to listen to the object's change inside the array?

Comment: Does it work as expected? If not then describe the issue clearly, if it does then the question seems off topic.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Yes, it is working as expected. Is this the right approach in this case?

Comment: I have updated my code. After the change in the code, I'm not getting update in the View Model class.

Comment: From your code, it looks like `OfferItem` is supposed to be a model class.  The question of which item is selected is usually maintained in the view or view controller.  What you are doing looks very unusual.

Answer (score 0):

```
class OfferItem: Identifiable, ObservableObject {
    
    //var status: String?
    @Published var isSelected: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            print("new value", isSelected)
            objectWillChange.send()
        }
    }
}
```

When you have an `ObservableObject` and mark something as `@Published` you're asking the system to send a message whenever the value of that thing changes.  The `@Published` property attribute will send the change notification on `willSet`.  Here you've doubled the notifications being sent.  The framework will send one on `willSet` and you've asked for a second change notification to be sent on `didSet`.  You probably shouldn't do that (note that you are calling object**Will**Change in a `didSet` that's logically inconsistent.

As a general rule of thumb, if you find yourself calling `objectWillChange` you should carefully reconsider if you really need to do that.  It might be necessary in special circumstances, but mostly should be handled by the framework.

On the whole I think you have a bit of an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here.  It's not clear what you are trying to accomplish and asking for the 'best' way to do something is more likely to draw opinions instead of answers.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion here. I am trying to listen to the changes in an object's property, which is the array element. Whenever the isSelected bool changes, I have to update my UI. Thanks for the suggestions. I will update my question.

Comment: I have updated my code. After the change in the code, I'm not getting the updates in the View Model class.